# Mapping json result in Data Fusion on GCP

Tags: json, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm trying to withdraw information from Facebook Graph API and convert the result into a readable form in Google Data Fusion using HTTP plugin to then upload results into Google BigQuery.

I've used this method in the past but in this particular case, I ran into an issue with a nested  object from the JSON response which is visible below:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "23850681132290191"
    },
    {
        "id": "23850605381460191"
    },
    {
        "insights": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "clicks": "13",
                    "date_start": "2022-07-18",
                    "date_stop": "2022-08-16"
                }
            ]
            }
            }]
}
```

So now to map the 'id' field, it looks like this:

[image]

And the result is the following:

[image]

So now when I try to map another field which is "clicks" - according to the documentation it should look like this:

```
insights/data/clicks
```

Assuming that the result path is "data"

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error:

Cannot convert line '{"clicks":[{"clicks":"66","date_start":"2022-07-19","date_stop":"2022-08-17"}],"id":"23850681132290191"}' to a record. Reason: 'java.io.IOException: No matching schema found for union type: ["string","null"] for token: BEGIN_ARRAY'.

I don't know how to map this particular field following the documentation they provided. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the documentation which you are following?

Comment: It's this one:
https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/694190359/HTTP+Batch+Source
I've seen that people struggle with Graph API because it uses weird arrays that are difficult to map.

Also, I've tried the following:
1. insights/data/clicks 
2. insights.data.clicks
3. $.data[*].insights.data[*].clicks
4. data.[insights].[data].[clicks]
5. $.data.[insights].[data].[clicks]

Comment: Hey @MarcinStańczak did you find any solution on this?

Comment: @TaulantRacaj hey, my solution was to switch to python and airflow for such tasks. However your solution probably works.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue is related when you have a list on a nested object. Therefore you would need to create a proper schema as below.

[image]

Hope this helps.